# How to scroll to top on a TextInput on render

Tags: react-native

I have a controlled multiline TextInput and sometimes the text may need to be scrolled.
On rendering some existing content is shown that may need to be scrolled to view.
I would like to "scroll to top" on render so that the user can see the beginning of the text.
Currently, at least on Android, the text renders scrolled to the bottom.

```
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.value}
          style={styles.textInput}
          clearButtonMode="always"
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
          onSubmitEditing={this.handleSubmitEditing}
          multiline
          numberOfLines={2}
          maxLength={100}
        />
```

And style as

```
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: '40%',
    maxWidth: '70%',
    textAlign: 'left',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-input-scroll-view`

- When the keyboard pops up, the `TextInput` will automatically adjust
  to the top of the keyboard.

**install**

```
$ npm install react-native-input-scroll-view --save
```

**Usage**

```js
         <InputScrollView>
            <TextInput />
            <TextInput />
        </InputScrollView>
```

Comment: I do not want autofocus as I have other fields as well above it. Still tried and it does not change scroll behavior, as expected just brings the field to focus after mounting

Comment: @rnk  Updated my answer

Comment: unfortunately no. It seems the behavior I want is available by default in iOS, only Android seems to have this problem. There does not seem to be a solution to this. Thanks for your help though.